# Transiting through Turkey two days before passport expires

Tags: transit, passports, turkey, ghanaian-citizens

I have been residing in the UK since November 2014 on a settlement residence visa which doesn't expire till July 2017. I left the UK on 04/03/2016 for a 11-day short visit in Ghana via transit through Istanbul (Ataturk) on Turkisk Airlines and return to London on 15/03/2016 via same return ticket. I have a Ghanaian passport which expires on 17/03/2016, 2 days later after I arrive in London. I have spoken with the UK Border Agency and they say there's no problem with me entering the UK so long as my Ghanaian passport hasn't expired whiles entering the UK. Can I transit through Turkey with the 2-day passport validity period, considering I reside in the UK?

Comment: While you should have no problem transiting through Turkey as long as your passport is valid, I would strongly advise that you renew your passport before travelling.  With the dates you provide, you are leaving the UK with only two weeks left on your passport.  If something happens and you are delayed by two days (for example, severe weather causes your flight from Ghana to be delayed by a day, which causes you to miss a connection in Turkey and another day's delay) - now you'll be arriving to London the day after your passport has expired - and, oops, back to Ghana you go.

Comment: Hi @Ernest 
Were you able to transit the Istanbul airport with 2 days passport validity ? I'm in a similar situation with less than 3 months validity, and would love to know if you faced any issues transiting.

Comment: @noobMama were you able to transit the Istanbul airport with your 3-month valid passport?

Comment: Yes it went smoothly, they actually don't ever check your passport during transit, you get both your boarding passes for the two flights in your departure country. And the boarding pass is all you need as long as you don't leave the international transit area in Istanbul. It was very smooth!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct!. you can transit through Ataturk istanbul airport (look for transfer to international terminal) with valid passport (not expired) along with UK visa.

There will be problem if you try to enter Turkey holding passport less than 60 days validity.

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/passport-validity-requirements-while-entering-turkey-in-accordance-with-law-on-foreigners-and-international-protection.en.mfa